# Finding mix string fix format data from text file from c# regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have text file which has data such as:

```
I and  team discussed and decide for JobNo ACK33938Y9   . Need to validate it . Next no : JIK24928Z9.
```

I need to extract data similar to `ACK33938Y9` and `JIK24928Z9`, which have a fixed pattern. Each text file contains different data with the same fixed pattern.

I have tried using this c# regular expression, but it does not give me the desired result.

```
^[A-Y][A-Y][A-Y]{1}\d{1}d{1}d{1}d{1}d{1}[A-Z]{1}
```

Can someone please point out what I am missing?

Comment: For starters the regex doesn't match the last number. What you've got there assumes the string starts with the matched pattern, so remove the `^`. Also, you can remove a lot of duplication: `[A-Y]{3}\d{5}\[A-Z]\d`

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply . I just tried but it does not work .

Comment: string expr = @"[A-Y]{3}\d{5}\[A-Z]\d";
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr);
            foreach (Match m in mc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m);
            }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
[A-Y]{3}\d{5}[A-Z]\d
```

Sample Code:

```
    string pattern = @"[A-Y]{3}\d{5}[A-Z]\d";
    RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

    foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern, options))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("'{0}' found at index {1}.", m.Value, m.Index);
    }
```

[Run the code here](http://ideone.com/EiaOGR)

Comment: you need to put your full code in the question then ... the sample that i have provided was tested before i submit it ....

Comment: Sure . Below are teh full code ;

public static void getReferenceNo(string text)
        {
            DataCheck();
            string expr = @"[A-Y]{3}\d{5}\[A-Z]\d";
            RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;
            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(text, expr, options);
            foreach (Match m in mc)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m);
            }
}

string data="I and  team discussed and decide for JobNo ACK33938Y9   . Need to validate it . Next no : JIK24928Z9.";
getReferenceNo(data);

Comment: Remove your DataCheck(); method and try .. the probem is there I guess

Comment: No . That is just a method for different purpose . I have debugged the code directly but It does not work . You can also try at your end.

Comment: I have updated my answer and added a link... click on it to see how it works live

Comment: @Rahul adding you code in a comment on this answer is not helpful. Please edit the question you asked (see the 'edit; link just below the C# and Regex tags) to include the code and also some data to validate. I think you should first read [mcve] and then edit your question.